# Flutter: How can I put an image on PDF

Tags: image, flutter, pdf, assets

I am using the example (https://davbfr.github.io/dart_pdf/#/) provided by flutter to produce a pdf document. I managed to output the pdf, but I failed to insert an image into the pdf. I would like to place the image in the same position where they placed the logo. I have tried several suggestions found on the forums without success. I thank in advance all those who will provide me with suggestions.
I trying add the code unsuccessfully ( have the message, my code is not properly formatted). But is the same as this example.

Comment: I saw this project .I realized that thay have createed pdf document using uploaded a pdf document on CardView on web. So you can also try this of idea.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by converting the image to svg format. it's a format that I didn't even know existed.